# C# fieldinfo from a field?

Tags: c#

Is there anyway to get a `FieldInfo` from a field without using something like a `string` with the name? Like:

```
class AClass
{
    String AField;
}

GetFieldInfo(GetHandle(AField));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; C# [does not have an `infoof` operator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/21/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue.aspx).

You can implement one using expression trees.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think I am going to make a class that uses dynamic method generation to create these http://evain.net/blog/articles/2010/05/05/parameterof-propertyof-methodof